# how to send message to target clients in photon server?

Tags: c#

I'm developing a multiple players game with photon server and unity, have some questions on how server send messages to clients.

I know that I need a List of clientpeer to save the connecting clients, but I dont know how to save a peer to the List，and which send-message code should I use？

//here is the List that saving the clientpeers

```
public class ClientCollection
{
    public List<PeerBase> clients;

    public ClientCollection() { }

    public void AddNewClient(PeerBase peer)
    //is it right that I send in a PeerBase type argument? 
    {
        clients.Add(peer);
    }

    public List<PeerBase> GetClients(PeerBase peer)
    {
        return clients;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can only send a message to one client at a time.  If you want to send messages to all clients you have to enumerate through the list.

Comment: @jdweng big thanks! I may use multi threads